# How to view changes in vmmap?

Tags: windows, memory-leaks

The VMMap help mentions "Show Changes" option in the "View Changes" help section, which sounds like a super useful option.

However, it is nowhere to be found.

I am using the latest VMMap v3.11.

Where is this option? How do I activate it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The help file is not accurate.  First you need to enable tracing of a process, File + Select Process and use the "Launch and trace a new process" tab.  Enter at least the Application textbox.  When the process starts, the Timeline button on the status bar will be enabled.  Click it to get a rough graph of VM usage over time, updated by default once a second.

Click and drag the mouse to make a selection on the graph.  The main window shows the changes.